# How can I use loop functionality in twig template?

Tags: 8, theming

I want to use a looping functionality in `region.html.twig` file to I can
wrap elements (Blocks in this case) that outputted from `{{ content }}` section.

Defult `region.html.twig`

```
{% if content %}
  <div class="Parent">
    {{ content }}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

The schematic generated Output:

```
<div class="Parent">
  Item_1
  Item_2
  Item_3
</div>
```

I try to use below code to create a loop and add a wrapper around of each `Item` outputted from `{{ content }}`:

My code:

```
{% if content %}
  <div class="Parent"> 
    {% for item in items %}
      <div class="child-wrapper">{{ item.content }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

The Final outpute that I want to achive:

```
<div class="Parent">
  <div class="child-wrapper">Item_1</div>
  <div class="child-wrapper">Item_2</div>
  <div class="child-wrapper">Item_3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be like

```
{% if content %}
  <div class="Parent"> 
    {% for items in item %}
      <div class="child-wrapper">{{ item.content }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

items should come first if it has data in that. And remaining everything is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help and reply, I test your code, but whatever I try I can't get any result!!!

Comment: items should come second. https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html

Comment: can u list your items structure here...

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you should look for items inside content.

```
{% if content %}
  <div class="Parent"> 
    {% for item in content %}
      <div class="child-wrapper">{{ item }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tested your code, but whatever I try I can't get any result!!!

Comment: what you are getting in {{ item }} now?

Comment: When I use `{{ item }}` nothing shows up.

Comment: replace content.items with just content inside {{% for item in content %}}. And tell what show up now.